# Json Serialization with Dartson

Tags: dart, flutter, dartson

Following the sample on the Dartson documentation page,

```
import 'package:dartson/dartson.dart';
import 'package:some_dependency/some_class.dart';

import 'my_class.dart';

@Serializer(
  entities: [
    MyClass,
    SomeClass,
  ],
)
final Dartson<Map<String, dynamic>> serializer = _serializer$dartson;
```

I'm getting undefined name `_serializer$dartson.useCodec(json)` and also wondering where _serializer is referenced from.

Yes, I have added the required dependencies to my pubspec.yaml.

```
dependencies:
  dartson: ^1.0.0-alpha+2

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^0.10.0
```

Comment: It doesn't look like dartson is still maintained and it foesn't look Flutter compatible. Why are younot using json_serializable?

Comment: There was still a commit to the project last month and they have a published road map. Anyway, i'll try out json_serializable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The required dependency on `build_runner` indicates that a build step is needed. Depending on how Dartson define's its builders it may be enough to run `pub run build_runner build` (or for flutter, `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`.

You might want to file an issue on Dartson to make the build instructions more clear.